# Set Warnings To Be Displayed Globally In SugarCRM

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

I want to set a message/warning which will be seen globally. How can I do this in an upgrade-safe manner? Right now I have implemented it as such:

**/modules/Administration/DisplayWarnings.php**

```
if(!empty($GLOBALS['sugar_config']['contact_name'])) {
    displayAdminError("My notification message goes here...");
}
```